# Vue.js External package consume components defined on base project

Tags: vue.js, package, libraries

Suppose the following scenario:

- I have develop a **base project which have defined some vue.js components** (globally to that project). Let's name them comp_A and comp_B.
- I'm developing **another project** (a separate node.js package) which **will be installed as a Vue.js plugin** on the base project and will act as external application, adding more functionalities to the base project (new components, new routes..).

The problem I'm facing is that **this external application needs to consume some components that are defined locally on the base project** (like comp_A and comp_B). **How do I achieve that?**

One solution that comes to my mind, is to externalize this common components into a separate library so they can be consumed by both of the projects. But that's not an option right now.

Comment: If the shared components can be moved to the Vue.js plugin then both the plugin and the base projects that import the plugin can use them.

Comment: Yes @Langlois.dev, but as I said.. that's not an option right now :(